# Accessibility of model map values throughout the pages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using `Spring MVC` in my web project. My project run through several pages and in each single page, it does some database operations. 
In my first page I add some values, say customer details in to the database and just after that, I retrieve the last customer id which is a auto increment value from the database. Then I add that last customer id to the `model map`.

```
String myCustomerId = customerservice.getCustomerId();
model.addAttribute("myCustomerId", myCustomerId);
```

Now my question is, can I access the model map value `myCustomerId` using `${myCustomerId}` in my last page? (the value was added to the model map at the first page)

**EDIT:**

it is accessible in the same page. (if I put `myCustomerId` in to `model map` in usermanagement get method, the `myCustomerId` is accessible in usermanagement page. but not in the pages afterwards. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding the `@SessionAttributes` annotation to your controller class like this,

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("myCustomerId")
@RequestMapping("/userManagement")
public class YourControllerClass {}
```

`@SessionAttributes` allows you to do is tell Spring which of your model attributes will also be copied to HttpSession before rendering the view.

Comment: the problem was not setting the annotation `@SessionAttributes("myCustomerId")` . now it is ok